# How to Sort Elements of Array in Arduino Code?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-ide, arduino-nano

/How Can i Sort this Array with Descending Order? I need Simplest syntax to use in iterative code.

```
lt[6]={35,15,80,2,40,110};
```

Comment: Have you tried `man 3 qsort`? - Arduino programming is nothing more than C/C++ so you can use almost everything available there. Know your Language!

Comment: Simplest, though not most efficient, is a bubble sort. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: Online version: [qsort() manual](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#gafd4bf2faec43342e7ad3d2ab37bac1fe) from avr-libc.

Comment: @Kwasmich no i am new in this field, please help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a programming question.

Comment: @EnricBlanco can i not ask any programming question?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a much better match for your question than this site.

Comment: @EnricBlanco but this site is much active in respond than stack overflow, so i tried this. So i request to open this topic for discussion as it is helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: @EdgarBonet , it really helped me. please upvote the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `qsort` is a good option:

```
// qsort requires you to create a sort function
int sort_desc(const void *cmp1, const void *cmp2)
{
  // Need to cast the void * to int *
  int a = *((int *)cmp1);
  int b = *((int *)cmp2);
  // The comparison
  return a > b ? -1 : (a < b ? 1 : 0);
  // A simpler, probably faster way:
  //return b - a;
}

void setup() {
  // The array
  int lt[6] = {35, 15, 80, 2, 40, 110};
  // Number of items in the array
  int lt_length = sizeof(lt) / sizeof(lt[0]);
  // qsort - last parameter is a function pointer to the sort function
  qsort(lt, lt_length, sizeof(lt[0]), sort_desc);
  // lt is now sorted
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Comment: @Johny Mopp it really helped me.